# LayoutInflater ignoring parameters?

Tags: android

I have the following xml object representing a ImageButton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/genreCellItemId" android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="5.0dip">
</ImageButton>
```

I try to inflate it and add it to a TableRow with the following code :

```
LayoutInflater inflater= this.getLayoutInflater();
TableLayout grid = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.bodyTableLayout);
TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.genre_row, null);
View myButton = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.genre_cell, null);
row.addView(tempButton, new TableRow.LayoutParams());
grid.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
```

Ok so I noticed that it didn't look as expected, so I fire up the Hierarchy Viewere and noticed that the ImageButton's actually have an layout_width = FILL_PARENT instead of WRAP_CONTENT, also the layout_gravity is NONE and there is no padding to be seen...

Do, am I inflating it wrongly ? Or is maybe the new TableRow.LayoutParams() part doins omething wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after nearly two days I have found the culprit :

As I actually suspected the new LayoutParams() is a problem if you already have "formatted" your View in the XML declaration...
So after leaving the new LayoutParams() out of the equation my Table would be shown just fine...

So just use :

```
grid.addView(row);
```

Comment: hi i'm inflating my view from xml and showing it in popup window, but its is missing its parent padding

Answer (score 18):

Try using `inflate(R.layout.genre_cell, row, false)` instead of `inflate(R.layout.genre_cell, null)` and see if that helps. Sometimes, the inflation works better when it knows what sort of parent the inflated view will go into.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.
still no padding to be seen and the buttons are still "glued" one against the other.
when using Hierarchy Viewer the layout_widt is still fill_parent and gravity is none. I do set a background after I inflate the ImageButton could that be a problem ? Also is the new LayoutParams() a problem ?

Comment: I noticed that also my Row doesn't get inflated well :

<TableRow
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/genreRowItemId"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:paddingTop="5dp"
 android:gravity="center">
</TableRow>

This one also doens't get it's layout_gravity set to Center but stays on NONE :(

Comment: It looks you may be incorrectly inflating everything. LayoutParams cannot be inflated without knowing the context of the parent. No (null) root (parent) during inflation means no Layout/Margin inflation.

Comment: In my case i'm setting the inflated view content to a `PopupWindow`, and hence `PopupWindow` is not a `View Group` i can't use it as a **root** while inflation. The problem i'm facing is that inflated view ignores the padding of its parent LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

For those using **Data Binding x Kotlin** and facing this issue:

instead of :

```
val binding = YourBindingClass.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
return ViewHolder(binding)
```

use this:

```
val binding = YourBindingClass.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
return ViewHolder(binding)
```