# Layout margin not applying to constraint layout in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am attempting to add spacing between views in the RecyclerView. Using the RecyclerView I have a repeating list of constraint views using a view adapter. On each constraint view I have set the layout margin to equal 15dp like so `android:layout_margin="15dp"`. When previewing the layout in design view I can see that the margin is being applied however when the app is compiled the RecyclerView.

The XML for the view being used inside the RecyclerView is as follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:minHeight="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/moment_timestamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="28 MAR @ 2:45pm"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/moment_text"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/moment_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingVertical="0dp"
    android:text="A kind man held the door  open for me today"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moment_timestamp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In design view, the component I am designing looks like this:

[image: design view]

However, when compiled and being used in the RecyclerView, the margins are not applied:

[image: compiled]

This is my code where I inflate the layout. Originally the width of the view was not being applied so as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview) I changed my code.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_moment, null, false);
RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new 
RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
return new MomentViewHolder(view);
```

Searched around quite extensively now and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LayoutInflater ignoring parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738670/layoutinflater-ignoring-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Try to to this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" //This line is the important one
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:minHeight="0dp">
```

Or what i always do:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp" //This line is the important one
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:minHeight="0dp">
```

Comment: See above, just managed to figure it out :) Thanks for taking the time anyway.

Comment: Nice, happy coding. =)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure out the solution. It turns out the answer that I followed to try and resolve the width issue was causing the margin issue. Instead of setting null as the ViewGroup parameter on the inflate function, I have now passed ViewGroup into the inflate function like so:

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_moment, viewGroup, false);`

Comment: you  should mark it duplicate. as there are plenty of question on SO related to ignoring params when parent is not defined